# splash screen picture doesn’t appear

Tags: java, image, swing, splash-screen

In my program I want to start it with a splash screen for some seconds and then start the first frame of my program ...

But there are 2 problems.

First the splash screen appears but the photo that was supposed to be shown in it doesn’t appear

Second when the splash ended, the first frame was to start, but it did not.

This is my code  ..... So I need to know what is the problem ?

```
public class Splash extends JWindow {

    AbsoluteLayout absoluto;
    AbsoluteConstraints absimage,absrra;
    ImageIcon Image;
    JLabel jlabel;
    JProgressBar Barra;
    public Splash(){
         absoluto=new AbsoluteLayout();
         absimage = new AbsoluteConstraints(0,0);
         absrra = new AbsoluteConstraints(0,410);
         jlabel=new JLabel();
         Image=new ImageIcon("sales.png");
         jlabel.setIcon(Image);
         Barra=new JProgressBar();
         Barra.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(410,10));
         this.getContentPane().setLayout(absoluto);
         this.getContentPane().add(jlabel,absimage);
         this.getContentPane().add(Barra,absrra);
         new  Thread(){
             public void run(){
                 int i=0;
                 while(i<101){
                     Barra.setValue(i);
                     i++;
                     try {
                         sleep(30);
                     } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                       //  Logger.getLogger(Splash.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
                     }
                 }
                 System.exit(0);
             }
         }.start();
         this.pack();
         this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
        new Splash();
        loginForm a =new loginForm();
        a.setTitle("fram 1");
        a.setSize(700,600);
        a.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        a.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        a.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could start by having a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915022/why-wont-this-draw-the-image/14915370#14915370) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802662/splash-screen-progress-bar-not-drawing/14803941#14803941) for a few examples

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing more, I would say you are having a combination of problems...

Firstly, this...

```
Image=new ImageIcon("sales.png");
```

`ImageIcon(String)` expects a file (from the local disk), here you're saying that the image must exist within the same directory that the program was executed from.  If the image is a embedded resource, you'll be in trouble.  You will need to supply a `URL` instead.

Secondly, I've got no idea what `AbsoluteLayout` is, but I suspect that it's a convenient way of saying `setLayout(null)` and without evidence to the contry, I would suspect that you're not providing any width/height information for the label, meaning it will 0x0.

You could take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926425/layout-manager-for-background-images-and-text/14927149#14927149) for an example of using a `JLabel` as backing container for other components.

You are also violating the single thread rule of Swing by updating the progress bar out side of the EDT.  This is a big, no, no.  You would actually be better of using a `SwingWorker`.

Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details.

The following a couple of different examples of the the same problem.

- [Why won't this draw the image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915022/why-wont-this-draw-the-image/14915370#14915370)
- [Splash Screen Progress bar not drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802662/splash-screen-progress-bar-not-drawing/14803941#14803941)

In answer to your second part of the question...

I would take a long hard look at `System.exit(0);` ...